# Stored Procedure not Working according to need

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What am I doing wrong? My stored procedure is not working according to need when using `=`, `>`, `<` as a parameter please help

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedp_Search] 
    @pAccountTypeId int = null,
    @pFirstName varchar(25) = null,
    @pLastName varchar(35) = null,
    @pZip varchar(10) = null,
    @pOperator varchar(2) = null,
    @pRating varchar(2) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    SET @SQLQuery = 'select 
                        at.AccountName,
                        U.UserId, U.FirstName, U.LastName,
                        U.NMLS, U.[Address], U.PrimaryEmailId As Office,
                        U.AdditionalEmail As Personal,
                        U.DirectPhone As Work, U.Mobile,
                        R.RatingStar
                     from 
                        [User] U
                     left outer join  
                        RatingReview R on R.UserId = U.UserId
                     left outer join 
                        AccountType at on at.AccountTypeId = U.AccountTypeId
                     where U.Deleted = 0
                       AND at.AccountTypeId = '+CAST(@pAccountTypeId as Varchar(10))+'
                       AND U.FirstName = ''' + @pFirstName + '''
                       AND U.LastName = ''' + @pLastName + '''
                       AND U.Zip = ''' + @pZip + '''
                       AND R.RatingStar = ''' + @pRating  + ''''

    IF(@pAccountTypeId != null OR @pAccountTypeId  != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND at.AccountTypeId='+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @pAccountTypeId )
    END

    IF(@pFirstName != null OR @pFirstName != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND U.FirstName Like ''%' + @pFirstName + '%'''
    END

    IF(@pLastName !=null OR @pLastName != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND U.LastName Like ''%' + @pLastName + '%'''
    END

    IF(@pZip !=null OR @pZip != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND U.Zip Like ''%' + @pZip + '%'''
    END

   IF(@pOperator = '=')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar = ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END

    IF(@pOperator = '>')
        BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar < ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END

    IF(@pOperator = '<')
        BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar > ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+
  'group by 
  at.AccountName,
  U.UserId,
   U.FirstName,
   U.LastName,
   U.NMLS,
   U.[Address],
   U.PrimaryEmailId,
   U.AdditionalEmail,
   U.DirectPhone,
   U.Mobile,
   R.RatingStar'

   EXEC (@SQLQuery) 
END
```

when i am using following exec statement its working fine

```
Execute storedp_Search 1,'Mark','Smith','48393','=','5'
```

but when using the same with different conditions then its not working.

```
Execute storedp_Search 1,'Mark','Smith','48393','>','4'
```

Comment: You cannot use `@pLastName != null` - this will **never** work. When comparing with `NULL`, you can **only** use `@pLastName IS NULL` or `@pLastName IS NOT NULL` - anything else won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you misspelled the operator inside the if condition, if i'm not wrong

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Storedp_Search] @pAccountTypeId INT =NULL,
                                       @pFirstName     VARCHAR(25)=NULL,
                                       @pLastName      VARCHAR(35)=NULL,
                                       @pZip           VARCHAR(10)=NULL,
                                       @pOperator      VARCHAR(2)=NULL,
                                       @pRating        VARCHAR(2)=NULL
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)

      SET @SQLQuery= 'select 
   at.AccountName,
   U.UserId,
   U.FirstName,
   U.LastName,
   U.NMLS,
   U.[Address],
   U.PrimaryEmailId As Office,
   U.AdditionalEmail As Personal,
   U.DirectPhone As Work,
   U.Mobile,
   R.RatingStar

    from [User] U
    left outer join  RatingReview R   on R.UserId =U.UserId
    left outer join AccountType at on at.AccountTypeId = U.AccountTypeId
  where U.Deleted =0
  AND at.AccountTypeId = '
                     + Cast(@pAccountTypeId AS VARCHAR(10))
                     + '
  AND U.FirstName = ''' + @pFirstName
                     + '''
  AND U.LastName = ''' + @pLastName
                     + '''
  AND U.Zip = ''' + @pZip
                     + '''
  AND R.RatingStar = ''' + @pRating + ''''

      IF( @pAccountTypeId IS NOT NULL
           OR @pAccountTypeId != '' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + ' AND at.AccountTypeId='
                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @pAccountTypeId )
        END

      IF( @pFirstName IS NOT NULL
           OR @pFirstName != '' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + ' AND U.FirstName Like ''%'
                          + @pFirstName + '%'''
        END

      IF( @pLastName IS NOT NULL
           OR @pLastName != '' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + ' AND U.LastName Like ''%'
                          + @pLastName + '%'''
        END

      IF( @pZip IS NOT NULL
           OR @pZip != '' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + ' AND U.Zip Like ''%' + @pZip + '%'''
        END

      IF( @pOperator = '=' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar = '
                             + Cast(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END

      IF( @pOperator = '>' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar > '
                             + Cast(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END

      IF( @pOperator = '<' )
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar < '
                             + Cast(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END

      SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + 'group by 
  at.AccountName,
  U.UserId,
   U.FirstName,
   U.LastName,
   U.NMLS,
   U.[Address],
   U.PrimaryEmailId,
   U.AdditionalEmail,
   U.DirectPhone,
   U.Mobile,
   R.RatingStar'

      EXEC ( @SQLQuery )
  END
```

Comment: where you have changed the code, still the same problem

Comment: IF(@pOperator = '>') inside this condition you used '<'. I think you misspelled. If it didn't fix the issue i will remove this answer.

Comment: got it , but still the same problem can you suugest any different logic ??

Comment: Before executing the dynamic query, Print it and check whether it is forming correctly as per your need.